# Fallback for Next JS Image component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

In Next JS `Image` component for using images from external URL we've to specify the base URL in `next.config.js` but what if the external urls are dynamic i.e., we don't know from where the images are coming from, then how do I tackle this case?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't seem related to its contents.

Answer (score 2):

you must use custom loaders for that

[next js document](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

```
import Image from 'next/image'

const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `https://example.com/${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`
}

const MyImage = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image
      loader={myLoader}
      src="me.png"
      alt="Picture of the author"
      width={500}
      height={500}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: What is `example.com`? Is it the base URL of our website?

Comment: @RishabSharma yes

Comment: Thanks @mohammad, it worked but I've to remove `https://example.com/` and it didn't applied any image optimisations even on those images whose base URL was present in the `next.config.js`